# How to get the error position of xml file with lxml dtd.validate function in Python?

Tags: python, validation, lxml, dtd

I want to check the validation of a xml file, sample.xml, associated with sample.dtd. But I can't get the error position. i just can get error message. How can I do that?

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import codecs

f = codecs.open('sample.dtd')
dtd = ET.DTD(f)
root = ET.parse('newace_JK.xml')
print(dtd.validate(root))
print(dtd.error_log.filter_from_errors())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the individual log entries instead of printing the whole result, for example

```
for error in dtd.error_log.filter_from_errors():
    print(error.message)
    print(error.line)
    print(error.column)
```

see http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._LogEntry-class.html